# How to avoid code duplication when multiple-inheritance is not allowed?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

I have a class `BaseClass` and a class `Subclass` which derives from `Baseclass` and overrides some methods of it.

```
public class BaseClass{}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass{

//override some methods
}
```

There is also another class `SimpleBaseClass` which derives from `BaseClass` and overrides some other methods of `BaseClass`, as it serves different functionality in comparison with `SubClass`

```
 public class SimpleBaseClass extends BaseClass{

    //override some other methods
    }
```

I want to confer in some cases the capabilities and features of the `SubClass` to the `SimpleBaseClass`. What is the best to do it? Is there a pattern to apply in that case? Simply though one can create a new `SubSimpleBaseClass` which derives from `SubClass`, copy the code of `SimpleBaseClass` and in this way has the functionality of both classes: `SubClass` and `SimpleBaseClass`.

```
 public class SubSimpleBaseClass extends SubClass{

        //do what SimpleBaseClass does
        }
```

But in this way code is repated in `SubSimpleBaseClass`. What is the best way to avoid it? Maybe `Composition`? Would the `Decorator Pattern` be an appropriate solution in this case?

Comment: Yes, Composition with dependency injection might help?

Comment: I think you need to reorganize your class hierarchy. If you need to make a not `beautiful` architectural/implementation decision upon implementation, then you need to reconsider your architecture. For instance make additional inheritance step and additional abstract classes which extend each other.

Comment: Without talking about patterns, if there is a commonality between `SimpleBaseClass` and `SubClass`, you can create a common ancestor for them which derives from `BaseClass` and let the others derive from that.

Comment: There are many ways to refactor code and restructure your modules. Design patterns help in finding what exactly to do. The _composite_ pattern, the _decorator_ pattern, the _favor composition over inheritance_ idea, and so on, are very valuable tools for designing you software. **But: What exactly to refactor is driven by the functionality you are trying to achieve. Or better: by the problem you are trying to solve. Technical issues should be never the motivation to refactor.**

Comment: @Davio: The problem is that SimpleBaseClass and SubClass have no functionality in common implemented in them, they override different methods of parent. Moreover, the final purpose is to create a derived class which combines their functinalities (without repeating code).

Comment: Since you can't do multiple inheritance/extending, you can just create an extra sibling as a wrapper for the other subclasses. Create a subclass of `BaseClass` and create a private `SimpleBaseClass` and a private `SubClass`. Reroute the methods you want to the appropriate other classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use a class hierarchy for the reuse of functionality. Rather use a delegation model where you refactor the functionality that is required for `SubClass` and your hypothetical `SubSimpleBaseClass` into another class. A simple example:

```
interface Handler {
  void foo();
}

public class BaseClass {

  private final Handler handler; // constructor omitted

  public void bar() {
    handler.foo();
  }
}
```

This allows you to implement a light form of "multiple inheritance" where you can still subclass `BaseClass` by multiple classes where you can still implement a common behavior for `bar` among multiple classes. This is a [common recommendation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), inheritance is often [over-used](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2010/02/13/composition-versus-inheritance/).

If this is for some reason not possible (your example is not detailed enough to tell), rather refactor your code to use utility methods. Never copy&paste your code. This duplicates the maintenance costs.

Comment: I like the delegation model, and i think the inheritance is too much used for factoring code.

Comment: I have finally it indeed so implemented, as recommended in your answer. Every functionality is moved to its class and all classes implement the same interface. The base class holds a reference of that interface and one can exchange the classes through a setter. In fact it ends to Strategy Pattern.